# How to add limit options while fetching data from bigTable ? Can someone give me the proper syntax to do so in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Currenlty I am doing like this

```
var [rowData] = await table.row(key).get({limit: 2});
```

Still am getting the 4 results instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me:

```
var filter = [
      {
         family: 'payloads'
      },
      {
         row: {
                key: identifier,
                cellLimit:2
         }
      }
];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to get 2 columns in an individual row there are a few ways to do that using filters.

You can use the cells per row filter:

```
const filter = {
    row: {
      cellLimit: 2,
    },
};

await table
    .createReadStream({
    filter,
    })
    .on('error', err => {
    // Handle the error.
    console.log(err);
    })
    .on('data', row => {
    // Use the row data.
    })
    .on('end', () => {
    // All rows retrieved.
    });
```

You could also do cells per column filter:

```
const filter = {
    column: {
      cellLimit: 2,
    },
};
```

The Bigtable filter's documentation is still a WIP, but [here are a set of code samples](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/blob/master/samples/filterSnippets.js) with various filters you can use with your reads.

I don't believe you can do a filter with a single row get, but you can create a scan that only reads that rowkey and it will effectively be the same thing. Let me know if you need more support on this question.